# Open Source ETL tool with JSON support under windows

Tags: open-source, windows-10, sql, json

For a old friend i "manage" his api connections and the necessary json transformations for repeating database imports.

I played a lot with different tools and solutions (SSIS, Powershell, ETL Talend...).

Since arround one year i use JQ for the necessary json transformations (removing, reorganisation etc). The tool is amazing and get the job done.

So far so good. My problem is the necessary development effort (i am no coder) to "develop" the necessary jq commands to get the data correct transformed.

Since three month the amount of new connection request exceed my free time. So may be it is time to rethink Thea pproach to transform the data and take a real etl solution.

So i looking for a [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) solution:

1. simple/easy
2. open source
3. works with heavy nested json documents
4. Windows compatible

any sugestions?

BR
Timo

Comment: "Since three month the amount of new connection request exceed my free time". Sounds like 1) your "friend" should have been paying you - especially if he runs a business and is making profit on this. Maybe not so much if it is just private data, and 2) sounds like it is time for him to start paying someone else.

Comment: Are you sure it must be open-source, or just free, no money? Which database?

Comment: Hi Mawg, Normally i would say: yes your are right (with both Points). But it is for an non profit organisation. Just free and no Money. SQL Server would be nice but that is not necessary. An Export as modified json is also possible. Rgds Timo